# How to fix the displaying of data on refreshing dataTable on ajax reload using an external button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Hi I am facing an issue with refresh of dataTable.
HTML code:

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
    <button type="button" id="refreshList" class="btn btn-primary"  style="
        float: right;
        top: 28;
        position:  relative;
        right: 240px;
        /* overflow: overlay; */
        z-index: 10;
    ">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Refresh
    </button>
    <table  id="show-jobs" class="table table-hover" >
        <thead>

          <tr>
            <th>Job ID</th>
            <th>Client</th>
            <th>Started At</th>
            <th>Ended At</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Report</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In the above HTML code, I have the table , which I am using in separate js file to render by calling the `.DataTable()` plugin. My requirement is that I have another button mentioned above, on click of which the data will be reloaded. The table is working fine, but on hitting the refresh button, the pagination doesnt seem to work as all the records are getting displayed in one go.Is there a way to stop that? Here below is the JS script I am using:

```js
var myTable;

$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("prior to calling the load function");
//loadJobs();
loadJobs3();


$("#refreshList").click(function(){
    console.log("hello from refresh");
    myTable.ajax.url("rest/webservice/jobs").load;
    console.log("hello after refresh");
});

  console.log("after calling the load jobs function");
 });

 function loadJobs3() {
  console.log("started")
        var jobList;

        $.ajax({

            url : 'rest/webservice/jobs',
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType : "json",

            success : function (msg) {
                console.log("inside success json");
                $("#show-jobs tbody").empty();
                jobList = msg;

                for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                    var job = msg[i];
                    if(undefined == job.endDate)
                        job.endDate="";
                    if(undefined == job.jobId)
                        job.jobId="";
                    if(undefined == job.clientName)
                        job.clientName="";
                    if(undefined == job.templateName)
                        job.templateName="";
                    if(undefined == job.startDate)
                        job.startDate="";
                    if(undefined == job.userName)
                        job.userName="";
                    if(undefined == job.status)
                        job.status="";
                    if(undefined == job.outputPathLog)
                        job.outputPathLog="";
                    if(undefined == job.logName)
                        job.logName="";
                    if(undefined == job.outputPathReport)
                        job.outputPathReport="";
                    if(undefined == job.reportName)
                        job.reportName="";
                    createFormElement(job.jobId, job.clientName,
                           job.templateName, job.startDate, job.endDate,
                           job.userName, job.status, job.outputPathLog,
                           job.logName,job.outputPathReport,job.reportName);
                    console.log("complete success json");

                }
             myTable=$('#show-jobs').DataTable();

            console.log(myTable);
            }

        });

    }

  function createFormElement(jobId, clientName, templateName, startDate, endDate,
    userName, status, outputPathLog, logName,outputPathReport,reportName) {

    $("#show-jobs").find('tbody').append(
        "<tr><td><a href = 'rest/webservice/jobLogFile/" +jobId +"'>" 
           + jobId 
           + "<i class='fa fa-file-text-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></td>" 
           + "<td>" 
           + clientName + "</td>"
           + "<td>" + startDate
           + "</td>" 
           + "<td>" 
           + endDate 
           + "</td>" + "<td>" + userName
           + "</td>" + "<td>" + status + "</td>"  
           + "<td><a href = 'rest/webservice/jobReportFile/" 
           + jobId +"'>"+reportName+"</a>" 
           + "</td></tr>");
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Saptarshi Roy, it is because you are not passing  form data at the time of reload.